# Transfer memo from Excel 2010 to Access 2010 using VBA and DAO

Tags: vba, excel, dao

I'm trying to transfer a text from Excel 2010 to Access 2010. Due to the limitation of 256 characters for normal text I want to use memo. Now, after hours of searching I still have no solution to my problem.

To be more specific: 
This code reads the data (in this case text) and writes it into an Access data base. Due to the limitation for text I need to use Memo fields in the Access data base but after adjusting everything I couldn't find the data type for this statement (sSQL).

What I want to do is to change the following code: (reduced slightly to the relevant bits)

```
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sDb As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef

sDb = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DataBase.accdb"

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(sDb)

sSQL = "Parameters" _
& " SomeText Text; " _                       <<== Here << ==
& "INSERT INTO IT_Ticker (SomeText)" _
& " Values ([ SomeText ])"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", sSQL)

qdf.Parameters!SomeText = Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("A1")

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Debug.Print qdf.RecordsAffected

qdf.Close
db.Close
ws.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

I was thinking about replacing "Text" with "Memo" but it wasn't working. I also tried "LongText" and "String".

Comment: Not sure what you meant but "move a text". Do you want the excel sheet to be put into Access as a table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the table into which you are appending data `IT_Ticker` already exists. You were not specific about the `Parameters` you're using, but the code below works just fine.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sDb As String
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim userName As String
    Dim longText As String

    sDb = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DataBase2.accdb"

    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(sDb)

    'sSQL = "Parameters" _
    '& " SomeText Text; " _                       <<== Here << ==
    '& "INSERT INTO IT_Ticker (SomeText)" _
    '& " Values ([ SomeText ])"

    userName = Cells(2, 2).Value
    longText = Cells(3, 2).Value

    sSQL = "INSERT INTO IT_Ticker (UserName, ReallyLongText) Values (""" & _
           userName & """,""" & longText & """)"

    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", sSQL)

    'qdf.Parameters!SomeText = Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("A1")

    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Debug.Print qdf.RecordsAffected

    qdf.Close
    db.Close
    ws.Close

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```